# Windows 10 - Nginx & Symfony 3 configs

Tags: php, nginx, symfony

I am trying to setup my environment using Nginx and a fresh project from Symfony 3, both work fine on their own (either starting Nginx by launching php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 or starting the Symfony 3 project with server:run), however, I can't get Symfony working through Nginx.

The error message I get in my log goes like this:

```
2016/02/21 00:36:33 [error] 6260#1732: *1 upstream timed out (10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
```

And this is my code in nginx.conf for the server section so far:

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        root www/projects/mysite.com/web;

        rewrite ^/app\.php/?(.*)$ /$1 permanent;

        location / {
            index app.php;
            try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
        }

        location @rewriteapp {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /app.php/$1 last;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
```

I have placed the 50x.html file in my /web folder and it does show up correctly after the timeout...

Answer (score 0):

I can understand you are using Unix / Linux machine. This is because you haven't enabled (granted the privilege for upstream).

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect true
```

The upstream blocked by selinux by default. Please let me know if this fixes.

Thanks.

Comment: err I am on windows, I edited the title to avoid confusion :)